# Вопрос по узлам документа.

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с непонятной проблемой при ознакомлении узлов документа. Стенд:

Код `HTML`:

```
<body>
   <button>Просто кнопка</button>
   <p>Просто абзац</p>
</body>
```

Попробуем обратиться к первому (так мне казалось) дочернему элементу документа

Код `Javascript`:

```
var element = document.body.childNodes[0].nodeName;
console.log(element);
```

Смотрим в консоль и видим, что мы получаем совсем не то, что ожидали. В переменной хранится ссылка на объект `#text`, что соответствует текстовому узлу. С помощью не хитрых манипуляций выясняем, что в этом объекте содержится символ перевода строки. И, вроде бы, вопрос снят, но не всё так быстро. По идее, после элемента `<button>` тоже должен находится перевод строки. То есть ссылка такого вида `document.body.childNodes[3].nodeName` так же должна содержать объект текстового узла, но нет. В этой ссылке содержится элемент `<p>`. И вот это меня поставлио в тупик. Почему в первом варианте перевод строки учитывается, во втором - нет.

Пожалуйста, поясните, почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@LeD4eG](/users/1926/led4eg)](/users/1926/led4eg) Вы просто проглядели `document.body.childNodes[2]` вобщем дерво такое

```
document.body.childNodes[
0=>'#text'
1=>'BUTTON'
2=>'#text'
3=>'P'
]
```

Это соответствует:

```
<body><!--начало #text(document.body.childNodes[0]).................................
.конец #text--><button>Просто кнопка</button><!--#text(document.body.childNodes[2])
..конец #text--><p>Просто абзац</p><!--Тут ещё #text (document.body.childNodes[4])-->
</body>
```

У меня тоже такое бывает.Где-то что-то упустишь и неможешь понять свою ошибку:) Надо всегда в таких случаях переберать весь массив циклом например так:

```
var e="";
for(var i=0;i<=3;i++){
e+=document.body.childNodes[i].nodeName;
}
alert(e);
```

Comment: Да вы по моему и мой ответ проглядели ИМХО 

document.body.childNodes[
0=>'перевод строки и т.п'
1=>'BUTTON'
2=>'перевод строки и т.п'
3=>'P'
]

Comment: Теперь поняли?

Comment: на самом деле проглядел)

Comment: Ничего бывает не стал минусовать т.к. у (я думаю не только меня Имхо) самого так бывает :)

Answer (score 1):

При обходе узлов надо обязательно проверять св-во [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeType), потому что помимо `ELEMENT_NODE` существует еще множество типов узлов.